# Microsoft Office Access error

Tags: ms-access

While I am running on MS Access myapplication.mdb, I am always getting this error "Microsoft Office Access Has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience, send error to report , don't send...". I tried to create a new application.mdb then to import the database, the form and the modules but I couldn't because I'm getting the same error while I'm importing most of the modules.
P.S.: I'm trying to import the modules one by one but for the majority of the modules I encounter this error.
I tried to open an old version of myapplication.mdb then to import the updated modules but just when I selected the damaged application to import the updated module I got this famous error directly... 
Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Which version of Access? There is a fix for 2003: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945674 Have you worked your way through : http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

for interested persons:
I arranged this problem by "save as" one of the damaged module then open the saved one then compile the application and reopen it normaly 
and it works

Thanks anyway

Comment: You should also familiarize yourself with the /decompile switch, as well as best practices for maintaining clean VBA code in Access.